# Time limit for Google form

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I am designing a google quiz where I want to set the time limit for each question. Is it possible to set certain time to submit the quiz? Do i need to go for any add-on or something else?

Comment: Sounds like a question better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: The max you can do is to set an expiry (date/time) to a form with formLimiter addon.

Answer (score 0):

At this time it's not possible to set a time limit for questions on Google Forms.